# How to track esper query state and all window events?

Tags: esper

### For example

**select * from eventWindow.win.time(5 sec) group by attr1 having count(*) > 10;**

want to track current state of the above query after every 1 second. Am use

**output all every 1 sec**

but it output when query meet all the conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
insert into CountPerAttr1 select count(*) as cnt, * from eventWindow.win.time(5 sec) group by attr1
```

... and then

```
select * from CountPerAttr1(cnt > 10) // detect threshold
```

When you want to have the current count you can use "safeIterator" or "iterator" on the first statement. If you also want to output every 1 sec you could do:

```
select * from CountPerAttr1.std:unique(attr1) output snapshot every 1 sec
```

I think you could also play with the Esper "table" feature for sharing aggregation state in different ways.